# Parallelize operation on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this Python class below. It's job is to take a Pandas Dataframe and create classes based on the contents of the Dataframe. This creation operation can take a while so I want to parallelize it. Below I have the code that I have parallelized it. I take number of cores and split the Dataframe then pass it to workers. For whatever reason the code below (not exactly the code below `operation` function was long so I shortened it as it's not really as relevant) hangs and does not finish. If I take out the multiprocessing code in `task` it works albeit it takes a long time. How do I parallelize this?

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

class DFOperator:
    def __init__(self, df, num_cores):
        self.num_cores = num_cores
        self.df = df

    def operation(self, df, param1):
        # Does some operation on df and returns a dictionary 
        # with values as a class


    def task(self):
        splits = np.array_split(self.df, self.num_cores)
        with mp.Pool(self.num_cores) as p:
            async_results = [p.apply_async(operation, args=(2)) for split in splits]
            results = [ar.get() for ar in async_results]
```

Comment: Have you tried the parallelization with a reasonably small dataframe?  I'm wondering whether it hangs forever or whether the parallelism is actually making it much slower (it can happen)

Comment: `operation` is a method, so `apply_async` would need `self.operation` - this is pseudocode, so no big deal, except that if `operation` ireally is a method, the instance object would have to be serialized and that means your full df is passed to each subprocess. If you can, pull `operation` out as a function at module level.

Comment: What is returned by `operation`? That needs to be serialized and passed to the parent too. If this is linux, you could leverage copy-on-write to fork after the array is created and not actually pass it to the child processes. Or put the array (and potentially its results, if its still an array) into shared memory.

Comment: @tdelaney `operation` returns a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

As pseudo-code, that looks like it would work which makes me think the processes are not performant.

Edit to remove GIL comments (thanks BorrajaX)

If you haven't already, I would start at the beginning with a small dataset and a synchronous process. Use a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see how memory intensive your processes are, and add asynchronousity (that ought to be a word) as a final step

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module uses processes (not threads) so they shouldn't be subject to the limitations of the GIL. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)
*The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.*

Comment: @BorrajaX -- Right! It's been a while. It's `concurrent.futures` that causes GIL issues, right? Do you recommend deleting this answer? I didn't have enough reputation to comment

Comment: _"It's concurrent.futures that causes GIL issues"_ Yeah, anything that uses threads. _"Do you recommend deleting this answer?"_ Errr... I don't know... Up to you, though. There are other possibilities that, even with processes, could affect performance, such as when you transfer data from one process to another. Maaaybe you could edit your answer to add those issues? You also did bing up a good point about memory: If the processes start using swap memory, (basically: using the hard drive as RAM) that could definitely degrade performance **a lot**.  Up to you though!  